# Printing from Vector Tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox-gl, vector-tiles

Is there a good way to render vector tiles for printing using OpenStreeMap data?  QGIS is a wonderful piece of software, but it is better at GIS than cartography.  Ideally I would be able to design a style sheet in Mapbox Studio and then use another tool to render the images.  Mapbox studio is great for the cartographic elements of vector tiles, but it only lets you project in web mercator and limits printing to 1280 by 1280 pixels.

Am I better off using a more traditional mapnik and postgis setup?

Comment: This question should be asked at gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Btw, you can get a 2560x2560 image by clicking the "2x" option.